# Why does this IF statement in my django template execute if the evaluated variable is False?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm working on a django project that's not mine, but trying to add a local css/js option to the webapp.

In settings_local.py I added this:

```
if os.path.exists('templates_local/local.css'):
    LOCAL_CSS = True
    logging.debug('LOCAL_CSS: %s' % LOCAL_CSS)
else:
    LOCAL_CSS = False
if os.path.exists('templates_local/local.js'):
    LOCAL_JS = True
    logging.debug('LOCAL_JS: %s' % LOCAL_JS)
else:
    LOCAL_JS = False
```

which seems to be working (see below).  In my main template I added

```
{% if LOCAL_CSS %}
    {% compress css  %}
        {% include "../templates_local/local.css" %}
    {% endcompress  %}
{% endif %}
```

(the project uses django-compressor).

This works as I expect if there is a local.css file present, but if the file is not there I get an error:

> Caught TemplateDoesNotExist while rendering: ../templates_local/local.css

In the stack trace LOCAL_CSS is listed as being False. The stack trace unfortunately goes down to show the IF not finding the file (which is expected) but doesn't seem to include how the IF was evaluated, although it is executing as if it were evaluating to True... but at any rate, it's not helping me figure out what's gone wrong.

I also tried explicitly checking that `if LOCAL_CSS == True` in the event that the if statement above is evaluating as True simply because the variable exists.

At any rate, I'm hoping this is an odd detail I've missed about django so far, or something that someone with more experience would see right away what I've done wrong.

If you think I'm going about this in the wrong way, feel free to peruse my original question which had no takers:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975054/django-recipe-for-local-css-and-local-js-like-settings-local-py-for-app-with-m

---

### answered! - three separate problems

As is often the case, multiple mis-steps seemed to be a simpler single problem

What ended up working was actually pretty simple:

At [supervacuo's suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12082432/602581) and after some wrangling, I added a context processor, templates_local/context.py:

```
import os.path

install_dir = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
localcss = os.path.join(install_dir, 'templates_local', 'local.css')
localjs =  os.path.join(install_dir, 'templates_local', 'local.js')

def local_static(context):
    return {
        'LOCAL_CSS': localcss if os.path.exists(localcss) else False,
        'LOCAL_JS':  localjs  if os.path.exists(localjs)  else False,
        }
```

and added `"rooibos.templates_local.context.local_static",` to the pre-existing TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS list in the settings.py file.

I just had to switch the if statement in the template to an if not:

```
{% if LOCAL_CSS != False %}
    {% compress css  %}
        {% include LOCAL_CSS %}
    {% endcompress  %}
{% endif %}
```

---

### What went wrong?

#### Problem 1 - I was confused about what was available in the template context

See [supervacuo's 1st suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12082432/602581)

#### Problem 2 - Lack of experience/familiarity with the environment

I didn't catch/suspect that in the context of django of method like os.path.exists() executes from the location of manage.py, not the path/file.py from which you you invoke it (which makes sense in hindsight)

#### Problem 3 - flawed logic, too simple an approach, maybe something else

I suspect that if `TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True` you may not be able to have an include with a path string (e.g. `{% include "../templates_local/local.css" %}`) without getting an error if the file doesn't exist.

But at any rate, the way it works now (determining that the file exists and then saving either an absolute path OR False as the template variable seems like a more robust solution and is more readable in the template.

Thanks again to supervacuo, your suggestions and comments were really informative - I feel like I learned a good bit about django because of them!

Comment: I should mention - I also tried not setting LOCAL_CSS to anything if the file didn't exist (so that ```{% if LOCAL_CSS %}``` would only find the variable LOCAL_CSS if it existed), but that also didn't work.

Comment: How are you getting `LOCAL_CSS` into your templates; a context processor? However it is, please post that code too.

Comment: Er, I don't have an answer to that, so that might actually be the problem.  I thought that the templates had access to the settings by default. I guess that's not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this rabbit hole is getting rather deep (hopefully we can edit the existing question and answer down to something generally-useful once this is all sorted).

Relative paths (like `"local.css"`) to `os.path.exists()` are interpreted relative to the directory you were in when you ran `runserver`. So, although `os.path.exists('local.css') == True` in that directory, your debugging stuff needs to specify paths relative to `manage.py` (or just make them absolute for simplicity).

I'm not sure what `try .. finally` is meant to be doing here, but perhaps just do:

```
from django.conf import settings
import os

def local_static(context):
    # Make sure to return a dictionary
    return {
        'LOCAL_CSS': '/path/to/local.css' if os.path.exists('/path/to/local.css') else False,
        'LOCAL_JS': '/path/to/local.js' if os.path.exists('/path/to/local.js') else False,
        }
```

Once you've confirmed that's working as expected, build out from there (do your `if os.path.exists()` tests in `local_settings.py` *etc.*)

Comment: Ok, I see what happened there - thanks for your help, you got me back  on track. Also, after working with the code you gave me here, I was able to get all the logic smushed into context.py (which is great, as I had a side goal of not requiring install sites to have to add something manually to settings_local.py after they updated to avoid breaking their installed app)

Comment: Also, I'm going to take a pass at editing my rabbit hole up there - you're right, way too confusing

Answer (score 3):

*(based on your comment reply)*

You're not actually passing your new `LOCAL_CSS` variable to the template, which is definitely a problem you need to solve before going any further. *Some* values from `settings.py` are available (*e.g.* `MEDIA_URL`) by default, but these are added by [Django's default context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext), defined in [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS). `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` is available, for instance, because of [`django.core.context_processors.media`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-media).

The best way, then, to add a context variable to every page is a [custom context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors). Something along the lines of:

```
# app/context.py
from django.conf import settings

def local_static(context):
    # Make sure to return a dictionary
    return {
        'LOCAL_CSS': settings.LOCAL_CSS,
        'LOCAL_JS': settings.LOCAL_JS,
    }

# settings.py
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # ... keep the defaults
    'app.context.local_static'
)
LOCAL_CSS = 'foo'

# template.html
{{ LOCAL_CSS }}
{# should output "foo" #}
```

For this to work, you should be using a `RequestContext` rather than a plain `Context` to render your template; the Django docs say :

> If you're using Django's `render_to_response()` shortcut to populate a template with the contents of a dictionary, your template will be passed a `Context` instance by default (not a `RequestContext`). To use a `RequestContext` in your template rendering, pass an optional third argument to `render_to_response()`: a `RequestContext` instance

The easiest way to do this is by [using `render()` instead of `render_to_response()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), in fact.

Comment: Thanks for this reply -  I added info to update the question, but unfortunately the question remains (the statement still executes when the variable is False), but thanks to you I have an answer to your question above ;-)